# Eliminating theta problem

Tags: trigonometry

Eliminate theta if $\tan(\theta - \alpha)=a$ and $\tan(\theta + \alpha)=b$.

I tried using the $\tan (a+b)$ and $\tan(a-b)$ identity and adding the two equations but $\theta$ failed to get eliminated.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\tan(2\alpha)=\tan[\theta+\alpha-(\theta-\alpha)]$$

Use $\displaystyle\tan(A-B)$ formula

In case you need to eliminate $\alpha,$  use $\tan(2\alpha)=\tan[\theta+\alpha+(\theta-\alpha)]$ and $\tan(A+B)$ formula

Comment: thank you sir ! Please answer one more of my question which I am posting in a moment.